# how to get the wordpress nextgen gallery id

Tags: wordpress

i want to include slide show of images in the WP page.

I have downloaded and installed **Nextgen Gallery plugin**

from [tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcDM48cEjlA) i came to know that i have to include the shortcode

[slideshow gallery id="abc" width ="200" height"200"]

now how get the id of already created album?? i.e how i l know the valus "abc"?

[image]

in above what is is the id  ?

**EDIT1**

[slideshow galery id="1" width="200" height="200"]

when i write this ..in the  webpage the images arnt getting loaded..

[image]

when i wwrite [nggallery id=1] in the WP page

[image]

The images are getting loaded ..but they arent shown shown as slide show ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it under the column called ID in your picture, it is a number!

So your code will be
    [slideshow galery id="1" width="200" height="200"]

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in your picture under the column labeled "ID". In your example, Gallery 1 has an ID of 1.

And secondly, your shortcode is incorrect. In order to use the NGGallery shortcode, it needs to look something like this:

```
[nggallery id=1]
```